# Sending Duplicate Messages

Tags: python, databricks, sendgrid

I created a script in python to email with an attachment. I put it in databricks, and put it on a schedule. When I manually run this function, it fires only one email, but when it runs on the schedule, to emails are sent to each recipient. Although it sounds like a schedule issue, I believe it's a code issue - I was able to get it to work at some point, but now it is sending again.

If anyone can take a look at the code below and see if they can figure out why it would be duplicating, it would be appreciated!

````
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from datetime import date


def SendEmail(recipient, subject,message_records,attach,cc,bcc,df):
  server = smtplib.SMTP ('smtp.sendgrid.net', 587) # check server and port with your provider
  server.ehlo()
  server.starttls()
  server.login("apikey", dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "XXXX", key = "XXXX")) # insert secret name
  sender = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "XXXX", key = "XXXX") # insert secret name
  msg = MIMEMultipart()
  msg['Subject'] = subject
  msg['From'] = "noreply@noreply.com"

  msg['cc'] =  ", ".join([cc])
  msg['To'] = recipient
  rcpt =  bcc.split(",") +cc.split(",") + [recipient]
  message = """
<html>
  <body>
       Good morning, <br> <br>
       
     """+message_records+"""<br> <br>
       
       Thank you and have a wonderful day!
  </body>
</html>
"""
  if attach==1:
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message,'html'))
    filename = "ASN-" + str(date.today())+'.csv'
    attachment = MIMEApplication(df.to_csv(index=False))
    attachment["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename=" {}"'.format(filename)
    msg.attach(attachment)
  else:
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message,'html'))
    
  server.sendmail(sender, rcpt, msg.as_string())
  server.close()```
````

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the SENDGRID library for python.  It uses the API key that you get from the service and it is built just for this service.

https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/v3-python-code-example

See if this code produces the same duplicate issue you are seeing.

If I remember right, send grid keeps track of the sent mail messages.  Make sure the "to - recipient" list does not have duplicate addresses.

I do not see any obvious issues with the above code.

Here is the PyPi link.  There are a ton of examples on usage.

https://pypi.org/project/sendgrid/